# Export Profile Manager database

Tags: macos, server.app, profile-manager, postgresql

Good morning,
I have an old Apple server with macOS 10.12 and Server.app version 5.3

Now I need export the information about devices with DeviceName, SerialNumber and ICCID (for iPad)

I found some thread with command for read information with PostgreSQL, but no one with ICCID information.

Someone know the correct select command?
I found this:

1 - connect to the database

```
sudo psql - U _devicemgr d devicemgr_v2m0 h/Library/Server/ProfileManager/Config/var/PostgreSQL
```

2 - If you want the names and serial numbers, use

```
Select "DeviceName", "SerialNumber" of devices;
```

I try to use:

```
Select * from devices;
```

And I see the title of the DB columns listed, but none traceable to ICCID...
Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if ICCID is even logged as the core question here? Last time I checked, Apple didn’t log that or need to log that in server.app.

Comment: On the profile manager web page I see the ICCID field (the SIM serial number) inside the device.
However, it is inconvenient to read device by device the information, so I would like to take advantage of the direct reading of the database

Comment: Cool - any issue uploading a screen shot (redacted) of this?

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I don't understand the request 